# Simple recovery password form

Tags: forms, symfony, dependencies, constraints

again, im trying a simple form for recovery forgot user password.

The form only contains a email input. The form handler, receive the email, search the user, restore your password and send a email with the new password. Is important says that user not is authenticated.

So, i need create a custom constraint that check if the email exists in the db. I have an method of a own service that do it. So, i need bind the method with the constraint.

The custom validation class is:

```
class ExistEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    protected $userService;

    public function setUserService($userService)
    {
        echo "Setter...";
        var_dump($userService);
        die();
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if($this->userService->existUserEmail($value) == false){
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }

    }
}
```

I inject the service from services.yml:

```
  validator.unique.ExistEmailValidator:
      class: AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Validator\Constraints\ExistEmailValidator
      tags:
          - {name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: user_email_validator}
      calls:
          - [setUserService, ["userservice"]]
```

The problem is taht, never inject the service, because Symfony says:

> Error: Call to a member function existUserEmail() on a non-object

Note: the user service id is: "userservice".

```
php app/console container:debug | grep UserService
userservice container AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Services\UserService
```

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 1**

My constraint class is:

```
class ExistEmail extends Constraint{

    public $message = 'El e-mail "%string%" no pertenece a ningun usuario del sistema.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}
```

And the form definition is:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('anUserEmail', 'email',
            array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new ExistEmail()
                )
            ));
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you run >
php app/console container:debug | grep UserService ?

Comment: Thanks, now set the id service correctly, but get the same error.

Comment: Can you add relevant code about the way you're using/calling the ExistEmailValidator (mapped to your entity? within your controller/form? ...)

Comment: Update the post with the constraint class and the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace,

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return get_class($this).'Validator';
}
```

in your `ExistEmail` constraint class by,

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'user_email_validator';
}
```

in order to map your constraint with the right instance of `ExistEmailValidator` (The one instantiated in the service container).

Comment: Thanks for adding relevant code. I updated my answer, check it again.

Comment: Perfect Ahmed, your code works ! you earned a beer in Argentina. The unique problem is that not show the form error message. Any ideas ?.

Comment: Thanks :) No idea based on the code snippets you shared, probably due to the way you're displaying your error messages within your templates.

Comment: the problem is that i query by the global errors. I have te call the specific field error ^^