# Custom constraint not show message

Tags: symfony, custom-validators

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818194/simple-recovery-password-form?noredirect=1#comment31218037_20818194) thread im fight with a custom validator. Thanks an stackoverflow user i can do work the validator. Now, i cant do that show the error.
The validator class is:

```
class ExistEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    protected $userService;

    public function setUserService($us) {
        $this->userService = $us;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if($this->userService->existUserEmail($value) == false){
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }

    }

    public function getTargets(){
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

}
```

And in twig i write `form_errors(myForm)`, but the error not shows. The validator works fine, but not set the error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can try to use the [`addViolationAt()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471812/conditional-field-validation-that-depends-on-another-field/20472214#20472214).

Answer (score 0):

See the [Class Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) documentation. Class contraints are passed an object not a simple value. Have you set the correct annotation on your entity? For example,

```
use My\Namespace\Validator\Constraints as MyAssertions;

/**
 * @MyAssertions\ExistEmailValidator
 *
 */
class MyEntity
{
    protected $id;

    protected $email;

    // etc...

}
```

In your validator, you will receive an instance of MyEntity from which you can retrieve the email value and validate it. As mentioned in a comment above, you probably want to use addViolationAt as well.

I hope that helps and that I'm understanding your situation correctly. I'm sure there are better explanations out there though.